# A combinatorial proof of identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove combinatorial identities following:

1. $$
   S(n,k) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (S(n - i, k - 1)\cdot k^i)
   $$
2. $$
   S(n,k) = k\cdot S(n - 1, k) + k\cdot S(n - 1, k - 1)
   $$

where $S(n,k)$ is number of surjective functions from |X|=n to |Y|=k.

My idea of me nor to no avail, and I would be happy to suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It may help to say these in words, and ask in 1, for instance, why would you multiply by $k^i$? As in, what does $k^i$ represent when counting these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is false as stated: for instance, $S(3,2)=6$, but

$$S(2,1)\cdot2^1+S(1,0)\cdot2^2+S(0,-1)\cdot2^3=2+0+0=2\;.$$

For the second one, let $[m]=\{1,\ldots,m\}$ for each positive integer $m$, so that $S(n,k)$ is the number of surjections from $[n]$ to $[k]$. Suppose that $\varphi$ is a surjection from $[n]$ to $[k]$, and consider what $\varphi$ does to the set $[n-1]$; there are two possibilities.

- $\varphi$ maps $[n-1]$ onto $[k]$. Then $\varphi\upharpoonright[n-1]$, the restriction of $\varphi$ to $[n-1]$, is one of the $S(n-1,k)$ surjections from $[n-1]$ to $[k]$. How many different surjections from $[n]$ to $[k]$ have this same restriction to $[n-1]$?
- $\varphi$ maps $[n-1]$ onto a set $Y\subseteq[k]$ such that $|Y|=k-1$. There are $S(n-1,k-1)$ surjections from $[n-1]$ to $Y$. In how many ways can each of them be extended to a surjection from $[n]$ to $[k]$? How many subsets $Y$ of $[k]$ have cardinality $k-1$?

$$S(n,k)=k\big(S(n-1,k)+S(n-1,k-1)\big)$$

**Added:** For completeness I’ll add an argument for the corrected first identity,

$$S(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^nk^iS(n-i,k-1)\;.$$

Note that the upper limit of the summation can actually be taken to be $n-k+1$, since $S(n-i,k-1)=0$ for larger values of $i$. Thus, we can rewrite the identity as

$$S(n,k)=\sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1}k^{n-i}S(i,k-1)\;.$$

Suppose that $\varphi$ maps $[n]$ onto $[k]$. We can specify $\varphi$ completely and uniquely by specifying

- the smallest $\ell\in[n]$ such that $\varphi(\ell)=k$;
- the smallest $m\in[n]$ such that $\varphi$ maps $[m]\setminus\{\ell\}$ onto $[k-1]$;
- the function $\psi=\varphi\upharpoonright\big([m]\setminus\{\ell\}\big)$, the restriction of $\varphi$ to $[m]\setminus\{\ell\}$; and
- the function $\varphi\upharpoonright\left([n]\setminus\big([m]\cup\{\ell\}\big)\right)$.

There are $k$ possible values of $\ell$. Let $i=|[m]\setminus\{\ell\}|$; there are $S(i,k-1)$ possible functions $\varphi\upharpoonright\big([m]\setminus\{\ell\}\big)$, and $i$ can be any integer satisfying $k-1\le i\le n-1$. The range of the function $\varphi\upharpoonright\big([m]\cup\{\ell\}\big)$ is all of $[k]$, so $\varphi\upharpoonright\left([n]\setminus\big([m]\cup\{\ell\}\big)\right)$ can be any function from $[n]\setminus\big([m]\cup\{\ell\}\big)$ to $[k]$; $|[n]\cup\{\ell\}|=i+1$, so there are $k^{n-(i-1)}$ such functions. Thus,

$$S(n,k)=\sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1}k\cdot S(i,k-1)\cdot k^{n-i-1}=\sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1}k^{n-i}S(i,k-1)\;,$$

as desired.

Comment: In the first formula was a mistake, I corrected it.
As far as I understand, in this case, the first multiplication on k - is a number of displaies one of the other i elements of X in the remaining element of Y, and other multiplications on k - are number of ways to distribute last i-1 elements. And this gives a total of $S(n,k)$. Thanks for the help!